'No qualifying bean' when I try to acces a function annotated with @Bean from mave a package in a parent maven project
I am trying to create a multi-module maven project, and I want to have a package shared among all modules, so here are some code snippets that I used:
parent project: basic-web-automation
is having this pom file:
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.basic</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic-web-automation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>basic-web-automation</name>
    <description>basic web automation project with Spring Boot</description>
    <modules>
        <module>basic-first-module</module>
    </modules>

and that parent is having FakerConfig class as following in src/main:
package com.basic.web.automation.config;

import com.github.javafaker.Faker;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Lazy
@Configuration
public class FakerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Faker getFaker(){
        return new Faker();
    }
}

and the first module is having those classes:
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.basic.first.module.entities"})
public class BasicFirstModuleWebApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BasicFirstModuleWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}

and and I have this test in first-module test package:
package com.basic.first.module;

import com.github.javafaker.Faker;
import com.basic.first.module.entities.User;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest(classes = { BasicFirstModuleWebApplication.class })
class BasicFirstModuleWebApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private User user;

    @Autowired
    private Faker faker;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        user.printDetails();
        System.out.println("faker: " + this.faker.name().firstName());

    }

}

and when I run I get this error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.github.javafaker.Faker' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1880)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784)


The configuration isn't included with an @Import nor is the component scanning doing anything with the com.basic.web.automation.config package. So obviously that won't be included as a bean.

@M.Deinum , thank you for suggesting this, now I understood how the @Import used for, but how to do that @Import, while FakerConfig.class is in the parent maven project?

You can just add a package to the component scanning.
